# Access will only retrieve data from 1 table in a join with no where clause

Tags: ms-access

I am using MS-Access to get information from 2 tables. I have used inner join, left, right, and outer with all variations, and it will either pull 1 row when 316 are expected, all data for the fields in test with no values for the fields from test 1, or all data for fields from test 1, and no values for test. How do I resolve this? The actual fields had to be changed for privacy, but the below is the exact layout.

```
SELECT [TEST].a, 
[TEST].b, 
[TEST].c, 
[TEST 1].[D], 
[TEST].E, 
[TEST].F, 
[TEST].G, 
[TEST].H, 
[TEST 1].[I], 
[TEST].J, 
[TEST].K, 
[TEST 1].L,
[TEST 1].[M]
FROM [TEST 1] 
INNER JOIN [TEST] ON [TEST 1].[ID] = [TEST].[CLAIMSNO];
```

Comment: Are you joining on the correct fields?

Comment: Yes, the ID field in test 1 is the same as the claimsno field in test.

Comment: Are you able to glean something unique about the `ID` & `CLAIMSNO` values of the record which *is* returned by the `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Focus on the key columns of the join.  Inspect their data types in the table designer.  Are the data types identical and/or compatible?  Does each key column have an index defined?  Edit the question and include those details.  That kind of detail about the keys (data types of primary key, foreign keys; index settings, whether unique or not) are critical to answering this kind of problem, whereas the list of all other columns is not very useful here.

Comment: There are no primary or foreign keys in either table. I wan't the one who made this database. However, the data types of both fields that are joined are short text. Neither field is indexed.Does that help at all?

Comment: Also, it is not very useful to list a bunch of joins, followed by a list of general results **especially if there is not an obvious correlation between the two lists**.  In other words, you could says inner join returned 1 row with non-null values from both tables (316 expected);  `[Test 1] LEFT JOIN [Test]` return ..., etc., etc.  Also, how do you define an "outer join"?  It is not the same as a full Cartesian product (no join specified), so it is important that you list the exact join clause rather than just vague references.

Comment: That can be a problem.  If there are no primary keys, indices or relationships, the results may not be reliable.  It would be surprising if no rows match since Access can be somewhat forgiving, but a proper relational database setup requires proper key columns established for relating tables.  (Technically speaking, if there are no keys setup, there is no way for the database engine to distinguish one row from the next.  Access will maintain basic row information even if key values are not specified, but results of joins still may not be well defined.)

Comment: Could you post sample data for just the `ID` and `CLAIMSNO` fields?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot show that. I have tried rebuilding the tables with primary keys and indices. This has produced no change.

Comment: I'm willing to provide an answer with some data-validation and debugging advise, but even if the data and schema are private you need to be able to at least share certain details so they can be discussed in a reasonable manner.  It's just not useful to debug abstract information.  At least edit the question and include the following:  Precise data types of the *key* fields with critical properties, like `[Test 1].[ID]` is Short Text of length 255, required (or not), allows zero-length (or not), indexed duplicates or no duplicates, primary key, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data-validation and debugging exercise, so if you can't share concrete example data then there is really no definite answer to this question.  Technically it may not be answerable according to common StackOverflow standards, but I feel generous right now.

Since the joined fields are text, there are various possibilities keeping them from matching: extra spaces, null-terminated strings, case sensitivity (although Access by default should be case insensitive), wide (Unicode) vs narrow (ASCII, UTF-8) encoding, etc.  You did not reveal where the data came from, nor how it was loaded into the database, so I make no assumptions.  In order to understand the data and determine the reason for the failed matches, you need to investigate the details of the strings.  You could likely narrow the problem by investigating the source of the data values and understanding the range of possible characters, encoding, string termination, etc.

Since you are already having troubles matching data AND since you already indicated that the original tables had no primary key or indexes, I highly recommend **adding a new AutoNumber field with a unique index to each table, perhaps named `[AID]` (for AutoNumber ID)**.  Do this even if you have added indices to existing columns.  This will at least provide a reliable "handle" to select and refer to a particular row while debugging the other columns.

The big idea is to use VBA or other built-in functions to inspect and report on various attributes of the string values.  There are just too many ways you could do this, but my preference is to create a public VBA function in a normal VBA module and then call this function from an SQL query.  Although you could do this for every row, instead I suggest manually choosing rows from each table which you think should match... record the `[AID]` value for each row.  If the manually-selected rows don't result in anything enlightening, then run it against an entire table and see what interesting results you get.

Consider these functions:

```
Public Function CheckSpaces(val As Variant) As String
  Dim result As String

  If IsNull(val) Then
    result = "Null"
  ElseIf VarType(val) = VbVarType.vbString Then
    If Len(val) = 0 Then
      result = "Empty String"
    Else
      Dim temp As String
      Dim n As Integer, m As Integer

      n = Len(val)
      result = "Length " & n

      temp = LTrim(val)
      m = Len(temp)
      If n <> m Then
        result = result & " AND " & (n - m) & " left spaces"
      End If

      temp = RTrim(val)
      m = Len(temp)
      If n <> m Then
        result = result & " AND " & (n - m) & " right spaces"
      End If

    End If
  Else
    result = "Not a string!"
  End If

  CheckSpaces = result
End Function

Public Function NullChar(val As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim result As Boolean
  result = False

  If Not IsNull(val) Then
    If VarType(val) = VbVarType.vbString Then
      If InStr(val, vbNullChar) > 0 Then 'vbNullChar = Chr(0)
        result = True
      End If
    End If
  End If

  NullChar = result
End Function
```

And execute queries similar to the following.  Let's say that `[Test 1]` row `AID = 10` has `[ID] == 'name'`.  Likewise, imagine row `AID == 20` of `[Test]` has `[CLAIMSNO] = ' name '`:

```
SELECT [ID], CheckSpaces([ID]), NullChar([ID])
FROM [TEST 1] 
WHERE [AID] = 10
```

and

```
SELECT [CLAIMSNO], CheckSpaces([CLAIMSNO]), NullChar([CLAIMSNO])
FROM [TEST] 
WHERE [AID] = 20
```

Compare the returned values.  Is there anything that indicates a failed match?